# PrimeNG Calendar not reflecting date in modal

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, primeng

I am using PrimeNG Calendar control I am able to select and store date but when I fetch dates from say database and trying to set it by updating Modal. I am getting the following error :

[image]

```
<p-calendar  [(ngModel)]="bin.bidinstalledfrom" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
[showTime]="true"  autocomplete="off" required name="BIDInstalledFrom" 
id="installedfrom" class="col-md-12"  ></p-calendar>
```

**Component:**

```
 this.bin.BIDInstalledFrom='17/05/2018'
;// I have hardcoded the date in component for the ease of development
```

I have tried dates in various formats. '17/05/2018 16:00', '17/05/2018','1526572848' etc

I have also tried changing the datatype of modal property `bidinstalledfrom` to string,date,number. Same issue. And since I am getting error, not only am I not able to set the date but also calendar doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Primeng Calendar accepts Date object. So you have to convert your **date string** to JS date object. Eg:

```
new Date('17/05/2018');
```

And then assign it to your model.

Comment: Like I said I have already I had tried Date model. I have also tried what you have mentioned. Same issue.

Comment: Will you be able to share your converting part. So that I can have a look. Stackblitz sample may be.

Answer (score 1):

For PrimeNG Calendar you need to use the JavaScript Date object and do the instantiation correctly. For instance with `new Date('mm/dd/yyyy')` (see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp).

**Template:**

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="bin.bidinstalledfrom" 
            [showTime]="true"
            dateFormat="dd/mm/yy">
</p-calendar>
```

**Component:**

```
this.bin.bidinstalledfrom = new Date('05/17/2018');
```

You can find a working demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-38du98